# Django - approach to code repetition in Unit tests

Tags: django

Short introduction.
I'm just learning to write tests for my application. The application is an online gradebook.
Below is the code from the homepage view test. Only the login form is there. If the user logs in for the first time, he is redirected to the view that forces to change the default password. If this is the next login, it is redirected to the right view, depending on the user rights.
Problem.
In this test of the view, I had to create 6 users and related models (Student, Parent, Teacher), so I wrote the methods to create these objects (**create_user** / **create_person**).
In many future view tests, I will also have to log in users and use models (Student, Parent, Teacher). 

How should I repeat these steps? Two ways come to mind.
1. Convert methods to static and use them in the next test classes to create objects. Will the tests still be "unitary"? 
2. Copy the method definitions to each next test class in which they will be needed. Will this not break the DRY principle?

Which approach is good?

````
class HomepageViewTestCase(TestCase):
    password = 'testerspass'

    def create_user(self):
        username = 'tester'
        numbering = 0
        while True:
            try:
                User.objects.get(username=username)
                numbering += 1
                username += str(numbering)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return User.objects.create_user(
                    username=username, password=self.password,
                    first_name='Name', last_name='Surname')

    def create_person(self, kind):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(RightsSupport)
        permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type,
                                            codename=kind)
        if kind in {'student', 'parent'}:
            user = self.create_user()
            user.user_permissions.add(permission)
            try:
                school_class = SchoolClass.objects.get(unique_code='2a2020')
            except SchoolClass.DoesNotExist:
                school_class = SchoolClass.objects.create(unique_code='2a2020',
                                                          name='2a', year=2020)
            student = Student.objects.create(user=user,
                                             school_class=school_class,
                                             name=user.first_name,
                                             surname=user.last_name,
                                             birthday='2010-03-29')
            if kind == 'student':
                return student
            if kind == 'parent':
                user = self.create_user()
                user.user_permissions.add(permission)
                return Parent.objects.create(user=user, student=student,
                                             name=user.first_name,
                                             surname=user.last_name)
        if kind == 'teacher':
            user = self.create_user()
            user.user_permissions.add(permission)
            return Teacher.objects.create(user=user, name=user.first_name,
                                          surname=user.last_name)

    def setUp(self):
        # Create users and student/parent/teacher models objects to test login
        # by homepage
        self.student_1 = self.create_person('student')
        self.student_1_form_data = {'username': self.student_1.user.username,
                                    'password': self.password}
        self.student_2 = self.create_person('student')
        self.student_2.first_login = False
        self.student_2.save()
        self.student_2_form_data = {'username': self.student_2.user.username,
                                    'password': self.password}

        self.parent_1 = self.create_person('parent')
        self.parent_1_form_data = {'username': self.parent_1.user.username,
                                    'password': self.password}
        self.parent_2 = self.create_person('parent')
        self.parent_2.first_login = False
        self.parent_2.save()
        self.parent_2_form_data = {'username': self.parent_2.user.username,
                                   'password': self.password}

        self.teacher_1 = self.create_person('teacher')
        self.teacher_1_form_data = {'username': self.teacher_1.user.username,
                                    'password': self.password}
        self.teacher_2 = self.create_person('teacher')
        self.teacher_2.first_login = False
        self.teacher_2.save()
        self.teacher_2_form_data = {'username': self.teacher_2.user.username,
                                    'password': self.password}

    def test_homepage_view(self):
        response = Client().get(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # Post with clean form or with wrong data -> not redirects
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 {'username': 'tester',
                                  'password': 'wrongpass'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # Student redirection tests
        # if first_login field is True -> redirects to FirstLoginView
        self.assertTrue(LoginForm(self.student_1_form_data).is_valid())
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.student_1_form_data, )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.student_1_form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/yourgrades/firstlogin')

        # if first_login field is False, redirects to StudentParentView
        self.assertTrue(LoginForm(self.student_2_form_data).is_valid())
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.student_2_form_data, )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.student_2_form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/yourgrades/studentparent')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'yourgrades/studentparent.html')

        # Parent redirection tests
        # if first_login field is True, redirects to FirstLoginView
        self.assertTrue(LoginForm(self.parent_1_form_data).is_valid())
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.parent_1_form_data, )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.parent_1_form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/yourgrades/firstlogin')

        # if first_login field is False, redirects to StudentParentView
        self.assertTrue(LoginForm(self.parent_2_form_data).is_valid())
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.parent_2_form_data, )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.parent_2_form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/yourgrades/studentparent')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'yourgrades/studentparent.html')

        # Teacher redirection tests
        # if first_login field is True, redirects to FirstLoginView
        self.assertTrue(LoginForm(self.teacher_1_form_data).is_valid())
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.teacher_1_form_data, )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.teacher_1_form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/yourgrades/firstlogin')

        # if first_login field is False, redirects to TeacherPanelView
        self.assertTrue(LoginForm(self.teacher_2_form_data).is_valid())
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.teacher_2_form_data, )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        response = Client().post(reverse('yourgrades:homepage'),
                                 self.teacher_2_form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/yourgrades/teacher')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'yourgrades/teacher.html')```
````

Comment: If you're using pytest, take a look into fixtures